# Search box Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

[Sheet I want to pull information from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuGsy.png)[This is where I want to information transfered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DGoP.png)I have recently made a search box that is pulling information from one sheet and is copying/pasting it in another sheet. The problem I am seeing is that no matter what value I have in the search box, the value that gets copied is the one I was last clicked on. When going through my code step by step, my TextBox1.value is correct with the item I want to bring over, but I am having trouble figuring out how to make sure when I click search that its going to perform the code to the item that is located in the search box. I will attach my code below, please if you have any insight it would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim search_value As String

Dim sheet_search As String

Dim sheet_paste As String

sheet_search = "Charlotte Gages"

sheet_paste = "Gages"

search_value = TextBox1.Value

Sheets(sheet_search).Select

If search_value = "" Then
MsgBox "This Gage does not exist"

Else


    Selection.EntireRow.Copy

    Sheets("Gages").Select

    ActiveCell.Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Sheets("Charlotte Gages").Select

    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Are you using Form Controls or ActiveX controls?

Comment: Your code is not searching anything, just copying a row from the selected cell.

Comment: I don't see how `search_value` even incorporates into this macro. As long as you type anything in the textbox this macro will run?

Comment: I feel like I need search value because if I don't have it, it just copies whatever cell was selected last and not what I type into my box

Comment: Are you searching through columns? Rows? The entire sheet? Some more context for this would be helpful, a picture would be phenomenal

Comment: Hey Dexloft, Im going to attach some pictures of what I am working with.